# Stubbing orientation configuration Android Resources in mockK

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk

I am trying to stub the `orientation` value of a `Configuration` instance on `Resources` using MockK, so I can test some landscape vs portrait behavior in my app.

Unfortunately I'm coming across something I've never seen happen with relaxed mocks.

```
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.content.res.Resources

...

    @Test
    fun `When behavior, verify result based on orientation`() {

        val resources = mockk<Resources>(relaxed = true) {
            every { configuration } returns mockk(relaxed = true) {
                every { orientation } returns Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE // Line 36, see stack trace
            }
        }

        ...
    }
```

Line 36 is throwing this exception:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.

    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.StubbingState.checkMissingCalls(StubbingState.kt:14)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.StubbingState.recordingDone(StubbingState.kt:8)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.done(CommonCallRecorder.kt:47)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:60)
    at io.mockk.impl.eval.EveryBlockEvaluator.every(EveryBlockEvaluator.kt:30)
    at io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalEvery(API.kt:92)
    at io.mockk.MockKKt.every(MockK.kt:98)
    at com.my.app.OrientationTests.When behavior, verify result based on orientation(OrientationTests.kt:36)

...


Process finished with exit code 255
```

I'm not really sure why its saying that since its a relaxed mock. Has anyone seen this? I'm having a hard time finding anything on line that mentions how to stub Resources and Configuration with mockk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case of [Java-Kotlin interop for getters and setters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters) hiding the underlying implementation:

`configuration` is really `Resources.getConfiguration()` (a method call), whereas `orientation` is `Configuration.orientation` (a Java field, not a method call).

Even though they look the same from the Kotlin side, the second `every` is failing since `orientation` isn't a method call that can be mocked out.

In this case, `orientation` can just be set directly without the `every`:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `When behavior, verify result based on orientation`() {
        val resources = mockk<Resources> {
            every { configuration } returns mockk {
                orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
            }
        }
    }
```